# Purple Ghosting/Fringing when merging to HDR

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

This problem pops up frequently when I try and create HDRs. I'll have a bunch of base images that I've corrected for lens defects such as chromatic aberration and distortion, and when Photoshop merges them, there will be fringing in the highlights, almost always when clouds are involved. Take a look below:

[image]
[image]

So far I've just painted over this with the brush tool in PS, but there must be a better way. What causes this, and how can I stop this from happening in the first place?

Comment: I don't think Photoshop doing a grat job when it comes with merging  HDR . Try use Lightroom it merge HDR better way and let you chose what and where to merge. and don't forget RAW images gives you a better results.